# How to set new date based on file creation time/date?

Tags: c#

Using the `FileSystemInfo.CreationTime`
E.g. `filename.CreationTime`

How do I set a new date based on that?

For example, could I do:

```
DateTime new_date = filename.CreationTime.AddMonths(3);
```

If that isn't correct, how would I accomplish that?

Answer (score 4):

Either via [`FileInfo.CreationTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.creationtime(v=vs.110).aspx) or via static [`File.GetCreationTime`-method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getcreationtime(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
DateTime creationTime = File.GetCreationTime(filePath);
DateTime newDate = creationTime.AddMonths(3);
```

If you want to change it you can use [`File.SetCreationTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setcreationtime(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
File.SetCreationTime(filePath, newDate);
```

Comment: @peters: consider to accept an answer if your question is answered :)

Comment: @peters: lol, not really: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You mean like:

```
new FileInfo("<filename>").CreationTime.AddMonths(3)
```